# Drools exception at high workload across threads drools

Tags: java, multithreading, groovy, drools

I have a Drools program running 6.4.0.Final and when doing some concurrency testing we received the exception below. The code creates a new kSession for every firing of the rules and disposes of it afterwards. There is no way that two threads could access the same session but the kBase is shared.

What could cause an exception of this nature?

The code is:

```
        KieBase kBase = ruleContainer.kBase
        if (kBase == null) {
            throw new RuleExecutionException("Failed to find compiled rules for package name")
        }

        // Set up the session
        KieSession kSession = kBase.newKieSession()

        ruleObjs.each { kSession.insert(it) }

        // Run the rules
        kSession.fireAllRules()
        kSession.dispose()
```

The exception is:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at org.drools.core.reteoo.NodeTypeEnums.isLeftTupleSource(NodeTypeEnums.java:84) ~[drools-core-6.4.0.Final.jar:6.4.0.Final]
    at org.drools.core.phreak.SegmentUtilities.updateRiaAndTerminalMemory(SegmentUtilities.java:380) ~[drools-core-6.4.0.Final.jar:6.4.0.Final]
    at org.drools.core.phreak.SegmentUtilities.updateRiaAndTerminalMemory(SegmentUtilities.java:381) ~[drools-core-6.4.0.Final.jar:6.4.0.Final]
    at org.drools.core.phreak.SegmentUtilities.updateRiaAndTerminalMemory(SegmentUtilities.java:381) ~[drools-core-6.4.0.Final.jar:6.4.0.Final]
    at org.drools.core.phreak.SegmentUtilities.createSegmentMemory(SegmentUtilities.java:171) ~[drools-core-6.4.0.Final.jar:6.4.0.Final]
    at org.drools.core.reteoo.LeftInputAdapterNode.assertObject(LeftInputAdapterNode.java:166) ~[drools-core-6.4.0.Final.jar:6.4.0.Final]
    at org.drools.core.reteoo.SingleObjectSinkAdapter.propagateAssertObject(SingleObjectSinkAdapter.java:63) ~[drools-core-6.4.0.Final.jar:6.4.0.Final]
    at org.drools.core.reteoo.AlphaNode.assertObject(AlphaNode.java:134) ~[drools-core-6.4.0.Final.jar:6.4.0.Final]
    at org.drools.core.reteoo.CompositeObjectSinkAdapter.doPropagateAssertObject(CompositeObjectSinkAdapter.java:494) ~[drools-core-6.4.0.Final.jar:6.4.0.Final]
    at org.drools.core.reteoo.CompositeObjectSinkAdapter.propagateAssertObject(CompositeObjectSinkAdapter.java:384) ~[drools-core-6.4.0.Final.jar:6.4.0.Final]
    at org.drools.core.reteoo.AlphaNode.assertObject(AlphaNode.java:134) ~[drools-core-6.4.0.Final.jar:6.4.0.Final]
    at org.drools.core.reteoo.CompositeObjectSinkAdapter.doPropagateAssertObject(CompositeObjectSinkAdapter.java:494) ~[drools-core-6.4.0.Final.jar:6.4.0.Final]
    at org.drools.core.reteoo.CompositeObjectSinkAdapter.teAssertObject(CompositeObjectSinkAdapter.java:384) ~[drools-core-6.4.0.Final.jar:6.4.0.Final]
    at org.drools.core.reteoo.ObjectTypeNode.propagateAssert(ObjectTypeNode.java:300) ~[drools-core-6.4.0.Final.jar:6.4.0.Final]
    at org.drools.core.phreak.PropagationEntry$Insert.execute(PropagationEntry.java:93) ~[drools-core-6.4.0.Final.jar:6.4.0.Final]
    at org.drools.core.phreak.SynchronizedPropagationList.flush(SynchronizedPropagationList.java:78) ~[drools-core-6.4.0.Final.jar:6.4.0.Final]
    at org.drools.core.phreak.SynchronizedPropagationList.flush(SynchronizedPropagationList.java:73) ~[drools-core-6.4.0.Final.jar:6.4.0.Final]
    at org.drools.core.impl.StatefulKnowledgeSessionImpl.flushPropagations(StatefulKnowledgeSessionImpl.java:2017) ~[drools-core-6.4.0.Final.jar:6.4.0.Final]
    at org.drools.core.common.DefaultAgenda.fireLoop(DefaultAgenda.java:1334) ~[drools-core-6.4.0.Final.jar:6.4.0.Final]
    at org.drools.core.common.DefaultAgenda.fireAllRules(DefaultAgenda.java:1288) ~[drools-core-6.4.0.Final.jar:6.4.0.Final]
    at org.drools.core.impl.StatefulKnowledgeSessionImpl.internalFireAllRules(StatefulKnowledgeSessionImpl.java:1306) ~[drools-core-6.4.0.Final.jar:6.4.0.Final]
    at org.drools.core.impl.StatefulKnowledgeSessionImpl.fireAllRules(StatefulKnowledgeSessionImpl.java:1297) ~[drools-core-6.4.0.Final.jar:6.4.0.Final]
    at org.drools.core.impl.StatefulKnowledgeSessionImpl.fireAllRules(StatefulKnowledgeSessionImpl.java:1278) ~[drools-core-6.4.0.Final.jar:6.4.0.Final]
    at org.kie.api.runtime.rule.StatefulRuleSession$fireAllRules.call(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
```

Comment: The source code is not Java. -- Is `ruleObjs` shared across sessions?

Comment: the code is groovy but i can swap for java if needed.. I mispoke before. No ruleObjs is unique per session. The "ruleContainer" is shared across sessions

Comment: Does it also happen when you use Java? --- If the elements in the container ruleObjs are not shared across sessions there should not be an exception. Does it also occur if you run all of these sessions but one after the other, i.e., start the second thread only after the first one has finished? -- Did you consider trying a later 6.x version, whatever the latest is at the moment?  -- If all of this results in negatives, you should report an error but it would need the full set of code and data to reproduce this.

Comment: It does happen if we use java, if the sessions are serialized to one at a time it does not occur.

Comment: Sigh. The only quick thing left to try is trying the latest Drools version. After that it'll need debugging using a minimum set of (Java) code that reproduces the NPE. Not sure whether a look at the (Java) code for the facts and for creating and running the sessions would give me an idea, but if you do post this I'll have a look.